# ASCII char in js with charCodeAt()

Tags: javascript

This is my code here.
I cannot use `/` because for some reason the `slug` cannot hold `/` but only ASCII characters, hyphens, dashes, and underscores, dont know why but fine.
So now I want to use ASCII to represent the `/`. Question is how with `charCodeAt()`. 
I tried this...

```
<% var slug = [title,post].join.charCodeAt(47) %>
```

It needs to render `title/post`.

```
Dec: 47
Hx: 2F
Oct: 057
HTML: &#47;
Chr: /
```

Comment: Did you try escape or double the `/`, e..g `var slug = "title\/post"` or `var slug = "title//post"`

Comment: What do you get if you use: var slug = [title,post].join('/');

Answer (score 0):

Actually I really don't know what you mean.
Anyway, found this :

```js
var slug = ['title','post'].join(String.fromCharCode(47));
```

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is a [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). It is a table where each character receives a number that allow strings to be represented in numeric form. The code for the `/` character is 2B (47, as you stated). It means that ASCII `2B` and `/` refers to the same thing.

For URL you can use `encodeURIComponent("yourTextHere")`, and it will transform to the pattern that URLs can handle.

For example: `encodeURIComponent("hello/world how are you?")`

Will return the string: `"hello%2Fworld%20how%20are%20you%3F"`

This is the only way to pass special characters through URL. It's not related to Javascript, but Javascript has that useful function.

The only other way to put the character "as is", is to find some Unicode character similar to a slash that is not the `/` (2B) itself. But it can lead users to mistakes when entering URL manually and should be avoided.